# bash loop and return (10 to 1 and 1 to 10)

Tags: bash, shell, loops, terminal

i'm currently working on a small piece of script in bash. As a beginner I can't find a solution to a little problem. 
I need to do a chrono which decreases with each iteration, but when it's equal to 0, it goes back to 10 (10 -> 0 then 0 -> 10). I wrote a small piece that currently doesn't work.

```
chrono=5
incremant=-1
 while [ $chrono -ge 0 ];
 do
  echo $chrono
  chrono=$((chrono+$incremant))
     if [ $chrono -eq 1 ];
     then
        [ $incremant=1 ];
     fi
 done
```

I know it's a really simple problem but I'm really stuck at it. Thank you in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: `[ $incremant=1 ]` doesn't make sense. What did you want to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure *why* you're complicating things with manual loops when `bash` has perfecly good C-like loops built in:

```
fn() {
    echo $1
    #printf "%2d * %2d = %3d\n" $chrono $chrono $((chrono * chrono))
}

for ((chrono=10; chrono > 0; chrono--)); do fn $chrono ; done
for ((chrono=1; chrono <= 10; chrono++)); do fn $chrono ; done
```

You can just change the loop sections depending on what you *actually* need, the current one counts ten to one inclusive then one to ten inclusive, so duplicates `1`. For example, if you don't want the duplicate, just change the first section of the second loop to `chrono=2`.

You can also perform *arbitrarily* complex operations on the value with the `fn` function (such as the commented-out bit which gives you a nicely formatted list of expressions giving the square of each number, like `10 * 10 = 100`). The current function just echoes the value:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to make it easier to read ;-) Perfect answer!

Comment: Looks great and easy ! thank you, will search deeper into that !

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same **without any loop** using `printf` and

- Bash: `printf "%d\n" {10..0} {1..10}`
- Posix shell: `printf "%d\n" $(seq 10 -1 0) $(seq 1 10)`

`{ ... }` is one of the bash brace expansion feature called sequence expression.
From `man bash`:

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer.  When integers are supplied, the expression expands to each number between x and y, inclusive.  Supplied integers may be prefixed with 0 to force each term to have  the same  width.  When either x or y begins with a zero, the shell attempts to force all generated terms to contain the same number of digits, zero-padding where necessary.  When characters are supplied, the expression expands to each character lexicographically between x and y, inclusive, using the default C locale. Note that  both x and y must be of the same type.  When the increment is supplied, it is used as the difference between each term.  The default increment is 1 or -1 as appropriate.

`seq` is a tool from the coreutils printing a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Initial value
chrono=10
#Initial increment
increment=-1
#as long as the value of chrono is in the interval [0,10] do
 while [[ "$chrono" -ge 0 && "$chrono" -le 10 ]];
 do
  #print the current value
  echo $chrono
  #change the value of chrono by adding the increment
  chrono=$(( chrono+increment ))
     #when the value of the chrono is at 1, change the sign of the increment to do the rebound
     if [[ "$chrono" -eq 1 ]];
     then
        increment=1
     fi
 done
```

**output:**

```
$ ./chrono.sh 
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**To review:**

https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Perform_arithmetic_operations
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_07.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: TLDP's documentation is somewhat notorious for bad-practice examples (particularly the ABS). [The bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are much better-maintained, as of course is [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tips! ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response ! I now understand why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {10..-10};do if [ $i -ne 0 ]; then echo "${i/#-}" ; fi ; done
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple for loop:

```
$ for i in {10..0} {1..10}; { echo $i; }
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```